# Partial Differential Equation - Excluding derivatives

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Hey I have following two PDEs:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial t \partial x_3}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_3} & =
\nu\left(\frac{\partial^3 u_1}{\partial x_3 \partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^3 u_1}{\partial x_3 \partial x_3^2}\right)
\\[2mm]
\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial t \partial x_2}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_2} & =
\nu\left(\frac{\partial^3 u_1}{\partial x_2 \partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^3 u_1}{\partial x_2 \partial x_3^2}\right)
\end{align}
Since the first PDE contains
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{3}}$ and the second term contains
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}$, is it possible to rewrtite each PDE by extracting the derivatives, leading to:

$$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial t } + U =
\nu\left(\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{ \partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_3^2}\right) {\Large ?}
$$
Or do I need to add the first two PDES leading to:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}+\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}\right)+\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_2}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_3}
\\[2mm] = &\
\nu\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2^2}\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}+\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}\right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3^2}\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}+\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}\right)\right]
\end{align}

I want to solve for $u_{1}$ while I already know $U$.

Comment: please fix the missing $\partial$ in your third equation, as well as the multiplicities of the $\partial$ in that same equation.

Comment: If $\nu$ is a constant, you can integrate the first equation over $x_3$, or the 2nd equation over $x_2$, which will give you the third equation in your question (after you fix some small errors) PLUS A FUNCTION.  The partial derivative of that function with respect to the variable you are integrating over, must be 0.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy thank you very much for your help. Sorry for the missing $\partial$. Is it correct for me then to assume that this FUNCTION you mentioned can also be 0 or is that to strict of an assumption to make?

Comment: @JuliusAngus You still have $\partial^3$ twice in your 3rd equation, where it should be $\partial^2$

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy thanks for mentioning it, I corrected it.